# Unable to login after registration with wp_insert_user

Tags: php, wordpress

I made a registration form but after the registration I am unable to login into the newly created account. Wordpress says ***wrong password for this email***, what am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
$userdata = array(
    'user_pass'            => $password,
    'user_nicename'        => $company_clean,
    'user_email'           => $email,
    'user_login'           => $company_clean,
    'display_name'         => $company_clean,
    'nickname'             => $company_clean,
    'first_name'           => $name,
    'last_name'            => $last_name,
    'rich_editing'         => false,
    'syntax_highlighting'  => false,
    'comment_shortcuts'    => false,
    'user_registered'      => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'show_admin_bar_front' => false,
    'role'                 => 'customer',
);

$user_id = wp_insert_user( wp_slash($userdata) );
    
add_user_meta($user_id, 'company', $company, false);
add_user_meta($user_id, 'primary', '1', false);
add_user_meta($user_id, 'miles', 0, false);
add_user_meta($user_id, 'phone', $phone, false);

if(!term_exists($company, 'customers')){
    wp_insert_term(
        $company,
        'customers'
    );
}

wp_redirect(get_home_url() . '/login');
```

I already tried with and without `wp_slash()` but the result is the same.

Comment: Do you want auto-login after user registration?

Comment: No i just want the user to enter email and password to login as you do in /wp-admin

Comment: Your exact same code works for me and I'm able to login. I did add `die($user_id);` before your redirect and got the id back. Is the user even added to wordpress?

Comment: Yes it gets added to the db --> https://ibb.co/HC9f70x --> https://ibb.co/Ky86frQ.

Comment: Just tried to reset the password, after the reset I can login without any problem, so there is something wrong with the password encryption, trying to understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, before registering the new user I was encrypting the password with `md5()` and then I was using that to register it.

`wp_insert_user()` does its own encryption so it was a double encrypted password, hence it was impossible for WP to match the entered value, with the messy one stored in the db.

Anyway searching on the web I found out that it is better to use `wp_hash_password()` rather than `md5()`.